acer AX1700-U3700A motherboard
I have a acer AX1700-U3700A that needs a new motherboard, since a capacitor started leaking. I scoured the internet but couldn't find a replacement motherboard. Does anyone know where I could find one or something that is almost similar?

That's a very old system. In almost any case, it'll be cheaper and better to replace it with an entirely new system. What are you using this machine for?

Never mind. I already found the motherboard by looking up the sticker on it.
